# Retrieve all key values from Firebase and append to an array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get key values from my database in Firebase and append to an array.
This is my query:

```
let dbHandle = Database.database().reference().child("userRecords").child(uid).queryOrdered(byChild: self.startDate).queryEnding(atValue: self.finishDate)
        dbHandle.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let foundRecords = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
            for record in foundRecords{
                let recordName = record.childSnapshot(forPath: "recordName").value as! String
                let recordTime = record.childSnapshot(forPath: "timestamp").value as! String
                let recordRate = record.childSnapshot(forPath: "recordRate").value as! String
                self.records.append(["equipment": recordName as AnyObject,"date": recordTime as AnyObject, "rate": recordRate as AnyObject])
            }
```

This is my database structure:

```
Snap (record1) {
"-LUmY5jC-jC6vwpQj26S" =     {
    recordName = "record1";
    recordRate = "1.2";
    timestamp = "27/12/2018 at 01:59";
};
"-LUmaAcxLcz1Oif4-L8n" =     {
    recordName = "record1";
    recordRate = "1.0";
    timestamp = "25/12/2018 at 02:15";
};}
```

JSON:

```
{"userRecords" : {
"l1GIK43GCUbdnnyYsrQnO3JLnjV2" : {
  "record1" : {
    "-LUmY5jC-jC6vwpQj26S" : {
      "recordName" : "record1",
      "recordRate" : "1.2",
      "timestamp" : "27/12/2018 at 01:59"
    },
    "-LUmaAcxLcz1Oif4-L8n" : {
      "recordName" : "record1",
      "recordRate" : "1.0",
      "timestamp" : "25/12/2018 at 02:15"
    }
  },
  "record2" : {
    "-LUmY7GRwo6_Iq6IqbN_" : {
      "recordName" : "record2",
      "recordRate" : "1.1",
      "timestamp" : "27/12/2018 at 01:59"
    },
    "-LUmaAcr1P2mQrtSdFWi" : {
      "recordName" : "record2",
      "recordRate" : "1.2",
      "timestamp" : "25/12/2018 at 02:15"
    }
  }
}
```

},
}

The query throws "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". All objects are properly connected.
When I change the query to:

```
 dbHandle.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

The query works fine.

The results are appended to my array "records" and then stored to a dictionary back to Firebase:

```
let reportsRef = Database.database().reference().child("reports").child(uid)
            let reportDict = ["reportNumber": reportNumber, "company": self.companyTxtField.text!, "address": self.addressTxtField.text!, "start": self.startDate, "finish": self.finishDate, "records": self.records] as [String : Any]
            reportsRef.childByAutoId().setValue(reportDict)
```

Issues:

1. I get the values appended to my array from "record1" only
   although there is also "record2" at least. How can I get all values from all objects in "foundRecords" and append the values to the array `records: [[String: AnyObject]]`?
2. Why does "observeSingleEvent(of: .value" throw an error?

*timestamp values have not been converted to NSDate format for demonstration purposes

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the actual JSON from `Database.database().reference().child("userRecords").child(uid)` (as JSON text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). There also is likely a better error message. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: Updated. The error message is obvious `Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10563cde0) to 'NSString' (0x103e2f5d8).`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra level in the JSON under each UID that your code doesn't handle. When you observe `.childAdded` that is not a problem, since your completion handler gets called for each individual child. But when you observe `.value`, you get called with a snapshot for all children. And that means you must loop over the extra level yourself:

```
let dbHandle = Database.database().reference().child("userRecords").child(uid)
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: self.startDate).queryEnding(atValue: self.finishDate)
dbHandle.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  guard let foundRecords = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
  for record in foundRecords {
    let recordName = record.childSnapshot(forPath: "recordName").value as! String
    let recordTime = record.childSnapshot(forPath: "timestamp").value as! String
    let recordRate = record.childSnapshot(forPath: "recordRate").value as! String
    self.records.append(["equipment": recordName as AnyObject,"date": recordTime as AnyObject, "rate": recordRate as AnyObject])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I get a new error `Value of type '[DataSnapshot]' has no member 'children'` for `guard let pushIds = foundRecords.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}`. I tried this way before and couldn't fix the error.

Comment: `foundRecords` is a `[DataSnapshot]`, which is an array of snapshots. Since `children` only exists on each individual `DataSnapshot` we need to loop over `foundRecords`. I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: "it doesn't work" What doesn't work? What happens if you run the code? If you step through it in a debugger, which line of code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I explained in the first post what the problem is. I have found a solution. I had to get all the keys for "records" and then loop over. This way it worked as intended.

Comment: Cool. Good to hear. If you could post that as an answer, others might benefit from it.